# FrontEnd that needs help to host a DB (.json)

Tags: json, database, rest, frontend, hosting

Is there a place where i can host my simple .json file but to also
do CRUD on the API?
Just like firestore firebase, but REST version of it.

Really need a place where i can just host it and create my small project.